# what if we removed any apple supplied system python which are in /system/Library and /usr/bin ? how we retrieve if we removed

Tags: python, xcode, macos

I was accidentally removed python files which are supplied by apple!

I think they are located at `/system/library and /usr/bin/python`, since I am not able to work on Xcode about python project programs.

Then while running the file, there was a pop saying:

> unable to spawn process (not a directory )
>   =>if I update mac Mojave to Catalina _ will this issue gonna fix or not ?

Comment: You'll probably want to reinstall `macOS`; it's never a good idea to remove anything natively installed which the system ultimately relies upon.

Comment: Formatted question for readability and adding tags to provide clearer affinity